# how to apply currency filter to input type=number? in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I use the currency $filter and format the inputs of type="text".

Now how do i do the same for input type="number"?

Angularjs will set the model to undefined if you key in any letters other than a number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do it in type="number". The type itself says it will not contain any alphabetic character apart from digit even if you put a comma (,), It will truncate from the input. But you can do it in another way.

Follow these steps:

- Create a text input at the same place where your number input is there. Number input should be at the top of the text input and initially, it will not be visible.
- When you click on text type input, the number type input should be visible.
- Add focusOut event on number input. When you enter any number on Number input, you apply your custom filter or condition and then set the value in text type input and hide your number type input.
- Make sure the style of text type input matched with number type input.